# user_profile_update_errors hook not executing

Tags: php, customization, hooks, users, user-registration

I'm trying to use the `user_profile_update_errors` hook, however it doesn't appear to be executing.

I'm calling it like this:

```
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'blm_register_result', 10, 3);

function blm_register_result($errors, $update, $user) {
    $errors->add('demo_error',__('This is a demo error, and will halt profile save'));
}
```

I've tried playing around with the `priority` parameter with no luck.

To test it all I am doing is clicking the register button and if it has any errors it will show them, but not the one I added above - if there are no errors then it will successfully register the user despite my error addition above.

Do I have to call this in a certain spot or what am I doing wrong here!?

Comment: I think `user_profile_update_errors` only fires when you add a user via the Users > Add New dashboard page, the public registration form has a different flow. Maybe try `registration_errors` filter.

Comment: @Milo Thanks man, not sure how I overlooked that one, but that did the trick :) Feel free to post as an answer.